# X, Y, Z — horizontal, vertical and ...?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, mathematics

When working in a 2D coordinate system you could say that X is the *horizontal* axis and Y is the *vertical* axis.

Extending this to 3D, is there a similar word for the Z axis?

<sup>(I'm aware of *Width*, *Height* and *Depth*, but obviously *horizontal* and *vertical* aren't synonymous to *width* and *height*, which is why I don't want to call the Z axis the *depth* axis.)</sup>

Comment: Z is also horizontal in this analogy.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it that does make sense since both axis would be on the horizontal plane. Is there an alternative I could use to differentiate between the two, or am I stuck with *depth*?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Notations_and_conventions) the three axes are called the _abscissa_, _ordinate_ and _applicate_, referring to x, y and z respectively. So although _applicate_ doesn't translate directly to the word you're looking for, this would be an appropriate notation to distinguish your axes.

Comment: @Urbycoz: I probably could generally, but I might end up talking about a horizontal difference between 2 objects and their widths for example. So I'd be using depth to mean 2 different things in a similar context. This is in the context of programming, where I'm after appropriate variable names.

Comment: Whatever symbols we may use, two of the axes are always in one plane. If x and y are horizontal, z is vertical; if x and z are horizontal, y is vertical. The words horizontal and vertical are generally used in a planar (2-dimensional) sense, not spatial (3-dimensional). Which is the reason you may not find a word corresponding to the third dimension along with horizontal and vertical. Don't forget there is the fourth dimension: time. :)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Maybe you could designate compass directions to the axes (e.g. north and east). Not a single word answer, but might help inform your variable name choices.

Comment: @Random832 I think OP already has N-S, W-E. (The compass is flat.) What next -- Zenith?

Comment: @Kris I think he means that you can use "North/South", "East/West" and "Vertical" axes.

Comment: I deleted my answer and downvoted. It seems to me this question has the narrow scope of naming a programming variable. The context/application of the axes is not given or explained. Neither it is said what kind of answer is expected.

Comment: With regard to how English, and language generally, deal with this and similar problems,  a look at [the Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) would be apropos here, especially [the second ("Space") lecture](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I doubt there is such a co-hyponym (if we can call it that) to *horizontal* and *vertical*. You'll need to use an alternative name.

If you imagine the 3 axes, then the Z would appear "on the same level" as the X one. Depending on which ones you consider, 2 of the 3 will appear as such and actually, they are.

[image: XYZ Cartesian Coordinate System Image]

If you look at the Wikipedia page for [Cartesian Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), under the section [Cartesian Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Cartesian_space) it says:

> *For 3D diagrams, the names "**abscissa**" and "**ordinate**" are rarely used for x and y, respectively. When they are, the z-coordinate is sometimes called the **applicate**.*

Emphasis mine. It says they are rarely used, but I doubt there are many other alternative terms, other than *Z-axis*, *depth*, and so on; they're the most appropriate terms, if you're looking for something technical.

Comment: Re: "co-hyponym": I don't know if there's a standard term for such things, but WordNet calls them "coordinate terms" (see http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wngloss.7WN.html#sect4), which in this context is rather fitting. :-)

Comment: @ruakh I wrote that part to make it clear that maybe the term wasn't the best choice, but it was the best I could think of to explain it :D

Answer (score 32):

In aviation we use the terms *longitudinal*, *lateral* and *normal* (or *vertical*) for the three axes. [See this description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_control_surfaces#Axes_of_motion).

Note that these are fixed relative to the aircraft, not the earth.

Comment: *normal* = perpendicular (to the horizontal, i.e., both longitudinal as well as lateral). These are with reference to the earth? Earth horizontal is really a curved plane.

Comment: With reference to the other two axes. It's still perpendicular to the other axes when the aircraft is in a steep banked turn (flying nearly on its side relative to the earth).

Answer (score 10):

### Original

Perhaps it's time to coin a new term? Here are a few possibilities I came up with:

- Applicatal (derived from *applicate*)
- Depthical (derived from *depth*)
- Zedical (derived from *Z*)
- Fordinal (derived from *forward*)

### Edit

Upon further research, it appears that in the realm of print media, they refer to the 3rd axis of linearity as "stacked". So you have **horizontal**, **vertical**, and **stacked** printing layouts. Here is a link to the best explanation I could find:

- http://www.elkriversystems.com/PrintedOutput.aspx

In hind sight, when making user interface layouts where the items move along the Z-axis (in a list), I have referred to them as being stacked. Given that this is in the context of programming, stacked may work for you if you're referencing the linearity of a layout.

Comment: Or maybe farcical (derived from ***far** away*) ;) jk

Comment: _stack(ed)_ and _layer(ed)_ are terms that are applicable in 2.5D systems, not in true 3D spaces.

Answer (score 8):

The axis, that is perpendicular to the plane of the graph, is usually called the **normal** axis.

Comment: Ah, no wonder there are normal force vector in physics that is perpendicular to the surface that an object contacts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force

Answer (score 5):

[image: Think Math graphic]

In describing the box or cube, you would use *height, length, breadth, width* and *depth*, with *breadth, width* and *depth* being interchangeable.

I would use a diagram or key to specify what you mean in your particular case.

- x = *breadth*
- y = *height*
- z = *depth*

Answer (score 5):

## horizontal, vertical, distal

There is no standard term for this, but [*distal*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distal#English) seems to fit both aesthetically and [etymologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_and_horizontal#Historical_definition) with the other two (*horizontal* from *horizon*, and *vertical* ultimately from *vertex* "highest point"), assuming the following perspective:

[image]

with *distal* referring to "distant" points.

Comment: ELU deals with established usage; suggested candidate words / senses are expressly  off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's certainly a technical minority use (as any answer would have to be), but it does have precedent in scientific literature, e.g. [*Optimizing distal landmarks: horizontal versus vertical structures and relation to background*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016643289400165C), [*Overestimation of Heights in Virtual Reality is Influenced more by Perceived Distal Size than by the 2-D versus 3-D Dimensionality of the Display*](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1068/p3053)

Comment: 'Distal' has a recognised standard meaning, antonym 'proximal'. I see no reason to suppose that the first article is using a different in-house definition; they certainly don't include it with vertical/horizontal in 'keywords'.

Answer (score 3):

Plain English words may not always suit specific technical usage.

As for variable names, you will have to drop the *h-v* concept and adopt the *xyz* nomenclature. Just remember in 3-D, the *z*-axis is the equivalent of the conventional 'vertical' (the entire 2-D *x* - *y* plane being the 'horizontal').

[see also my comment @OP]

Comment: Conventions for which axis is "vertical" vary across different domains and even within domains: sometimes it's _z_, sometimes it's _y_. The direction of the vertical axis also varies: sometimes the "up" direction is positive along the vertical axis, sometimes it's negative.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew In fact, a three dimensional object in space has no defined vertical or horizontal. Take a cube and turn it slowly along one of its axes: what happens to the original horizontal/ vertical plane? The plane rotates with the object. At what point does the 'horizontal plane' cease to be so and become the 'vertical plane'? :)

Comment: The "horizontal" and "vertical" of a _coordinate system_ are defined by use, though I agree there are some domains in which no such meaning can be applied. My point is that saying "the z-axis is the equivalent of the conventional 'vertical'" is inaccurate in general (though it's true in some cases).

Answer (score 3):

In my 3D coding experiences, we have called it the z-axis and depth. As well as z-values and depth-values used to mean the same thing. And also we rarely used horizontal and vertical, we just called those x-axis and y-axis.

Both of these answers are somewhat rejected by your question, but this is the answer I give based on my experiences. Maybe if you described the context of your usage, it would help.

Comment: right, we have to be specific, he is saying in a comment "This is in the context of programming"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming cartesian, affine, orthogonal coordinate systems wherein axes are perpendicular towards each other and usually parallel to the viewport edges, the *planar* 2D coordinate system (for specifying positions, *linear* paths and *areal* shapes) of

1. *horizontal* X-axis (*abscissa*) for designating *left* and *right* positions constituting *distances* like *widths*, *breadths* or (without a negative direction) *lengths*
   and
2. *vertical* Y-axis (*ordinate*) for designating *top*, *up* or *upper* and *bottom*, *down* or *lower* positions constituting *altitudes* like (positive) *heights* and *elevations* or (negative) *depths*

becomes usually

1. either the *plan*, *ground*, *base* or *floor*, i.e. what appears flat in *top*-view,
2. or the *canvas*, *face* or *facade*, i.e. what is flat in *front*-view and
3. rarely the *side*, *wall* or *fence*

of a *spatial* 3D coordinate system (for also specifying *volumetric* bodies). The positive directions conventionally follow the *right hand rule* with the thumb pointing towards X+, the index finger towards Y+ and the middle finger towards Z+.

### Bottom-Up Z-Axis

[image: 1st Case]
[image]
[image]

In the 1st case, especially used with maps, the Z-axis becomes the *vertical* dimension, which is often positive only, and either the X-axis or the XY-plane is considered *horizontal*. In the former case, the Y-axis has **no conventional designation** matching the *horizontal* ∶ *vertical* pair, and it is only ever used when both of these axis are oriented the same as the drawing canvas, which explains somewhat why there is no third term. In the latter case, **no designation is necessary**.

### Front-Back or Back-Front Z-Axis

[image: 2nd Case]
[image]

Only in the 2nd case, there are formal **alternative names** available: the third axis is called an *applicate* in environments where the others are known as *abscissa* and *ordinate*. This means, an applicate always follows the virtual line of sight of a spectator ranging – according to the right hand rule – either from negative *back* to positive *front*, e.g. in most paper diagrams with the origin in the lower left, Y+ pointing up and X+ pointing right, or from negative (or zero) *proximity* to positive *distance*, e.g. on screens and all other planar media inherently organized in horizontal *lines* or *rows* and vertical *columns* running from top to bottom. One could derive neologisms from these terms, e.g. ****abscissal* ∶ *ordinal* ∶ **applical* or **applicational***.

Layout systems often use the 2nd convention, but only support a 2.5D space with multiple planes in distinct, indexed and possibly named *layers* that are *stacked* above one another in a canonical order with a *thickness* of zero. The equivalent to horizontal-vertical *position* for the pseudo-dimensional axis would be ***level*** with the derived neologism ****levial***.

### Left-Right Z-Axis

[image: 3rd Case] 
[image]
[image]

### Relative Axes

[image]

It often makes sense to establish a relative, local coordinate system for any (moving) object in 3D space. Its *trajectory* (from–towards) or (if stale) *bearing* of its assumed line of sight, e.g. along a nose, determines the *longitudinal* axis. Its *lateral* axis is perpendicular to this, e.g. alongside wings, and together they span a plane that is often (approximately) parallel to the *ground* and which the third, *normal* axis is perpendicular to. This triple *longitudinal* ∶ *lateral* ∶ *normal* basically matches <wanted term> ∶ *horizontal* ∶ *vertical*, thus ***longitudinal*** could be argued for as a reasonable candidate for the third axis in absolute, global coordinate systems as well.

### Neologisms

Looking at a related language, there are native terms for *horizontal* and *vertical* in German: *waagerecht* and *senkrecht*, respectively. They either originate in or at least align with the desired states of beam balance scales (*Balkenwaage*) and plummets (*Senkblei*, *Senklot*). Accordingly, Ænglish cognates would perhaps be ****scaleright*** and ****plumbright***. There is no term for the third axis or orientation in German either, but analogous construction could yield something like ****eyeright***, ****sightright***, ****shotright***, ****wayright*** or ****pathright***.

Since X-Y-Z axes are frequently colored red, green and blue, respectively (cf. RGB color space) in 3D applications, and *vert* means *green* in French as well as in English heraldic tinctures, one could form neologisms to match *vertical* (Y), i.e.: **rougical* or **gulical* (X, synonyms for *horizontal*) and ****azurical*** (perhaps rather ****azurial***, ****azureal***, ****azural***) or ****bleucal*** (Z).

### Related Systems

[image]

Fortunately, most people do not have to deal with cylindrical, polar, equatorial, horizontal or other spherical and yet more exotic coordinate systems on a regular basis. Those require terms like *pole*, *horizon* and *equator*, *longitude* and *latitude*, *ascension* and *declension*, *azimuth*, *celestial*, *ecliptic* and *galactic*, *zenith* and *nadir*.

Comment: Your upper-left xyz diagram appears to be a reflection of what it should be.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same question working on a 3D interface today, and came to the conclusion that "vertical" (y axis), "lateral" (x axis), and "horizontal" (z axis) fit reasonably well.

- Vertical means ["being in a position or direction perpendicular to
  the plane of the horizon; upright; plumb."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vertical?s=t&path=/) (i.e., up-and-down);
- Lateral means ["of or pertaining to the side; situated at, proceeding
  from, or directed to a side: a lateral view."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lateral?&path=/) (i.e.,
  left-to-right);
- Horizontal means ["at right angles to the vertical;
  parallel to level ground."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/horizontal?&path=/)

By deductive reasoning (taking away the left-to-right perspective covered by lateral), we can conclude that "horizontal" is an appropriate term for nearest to furthest away (toward the horizon, as it were.)