# Terms for generic forms of 3D motion on the 3 axes

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider up & down, left & right, and back & forth. Up & down can be stated generically as "vertical". Side-to-side is "lateral". What about back & forth?

Comment: Regardless, it is *axial*. You can theoretically have a multi-axial displacement of an object.

Comment: True, but I need that specific term.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56472/x-y-z-horizontal-vertical-and ?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Totally different concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the word *longitudinal*?

[OOD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/longitudinal) defines longitudinal as "*running lengthwise rather than across*".

When we talk about waves in which the displacement of the medium is in the same direction as (or the opposite direction to) the direction in which the wave travels, [we often use the word *longitudinal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave).

[image: wave]
<sub>(source: [ddmcdn.com](https://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/noise-canceling-headphone-8.jpg))</sub>

In [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes) about aircraft principal axes, it states that

> An aircraft in flight is free to rotate in three dimensions: pitch, nose up or down about an axis running from wing to wing, yaw, nose left or right about an axis running up and down; and roll, rotation about an axis running from nose to tail. **The axes are alternatively designated as lateral, vertical, and longitudinal.**

[image]